# How can I start a server with Automator? (Mac)

Tags: mac, automator, minecraft

I have a Minecraft Server (kill me, right?) and I have a bash script to go along with it. Basically, right now I do this:

> Open Terminal
>   cd to /path/to/my/server/
>   bash start.sh

And voila. My start.sh file consists of:

> java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui

And that's how I do it. I have become tired of it, so I thought; hey! Let's make an automator file that is run when iCal gets to 4:30pm, so I don't have to do it!

iCal is all sorted, I have made an automator file, added 'Run Shell Script', but now I do not know what to do.

I have tried the cd /path/to/my/server/ and the bash part and etcetera. It completes the cd easily enough, but it just gets stuck loading at the bash part I know as I removed the bash part and it completed it.)

This is probably a noob question, but still, help please?

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste the absolute path and run script like that:

```
/path/to/my/server/start.sh
```

It should run the script.